# Ошибка в ajax запросе, сервер не видит параметр запроса

Tags: ajax, формы

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Есть сервер с API (не мой) на который я, с помощью формы на сайте отправляю файл и должен получить, соответственно, ответ.

Требования к запросу вроде бы простые, POST запрос с одним обязательным параметром:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю ajax запрос:

```
var formData = new FormData();

const fileInput = моя форма.querySelector('[name="upfile"]');

formData.append('upfile', fileInput.files[0], fileInput.files[0].name);

let params = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: formData
};

// formdata debug
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]); // здесь вроде бы все есть, в консоли пишет: upfile, [object File]
}

fetch('https://сервер/v1/upload', params)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

и получаю вот это (это то, что отдает сервер):

```
{detail: "Missing formdata parameter 'upfile'", status: 400, title: "Bad Request", type: "about:blank"}
detail: "Missing formdata parameter 'upfile'"
status: 400
title: "Bad Request"
type: "about:blank"
```

Получается, что сервер не видит параметр "upfile", хотя он добавлен в "body" запроса методом `formData.append('upfile', fileInput.files[0], fileInput.files[0].name);`

В чем тут может быть проблема? Правильно ли я формирую запрос?

Я, кстати, пробовал отправлять вместо файла простую строку:  `formData.append('upfile', '1');` Сервер все равно не видит это поле.

Спасибо!

Comment: [посмотрите](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery#answer-8244082) возможно параметр должен по другому называтся? могу я получить url вашего Api?

Comment: Да, конечно, вот тестовый запрос:  curl -X POST "http://api.r4slide.com/v1/upload" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "upfile=@Презентация тест.pptx"

Comment: А документация какая нить?

Comment: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/PintAr/R4Slide/1.0.1?fbclid=IwAR32HLbgBhDR2JiknieHCweiaYCbeOt6pHCPd59jFP1Lqhe5Y4T10zxOh6Q#/default    все, что есть

Comment: как то не понятно работает само api... у вас вроде все правильно....у мен даже с постмена не получается сделать запрос нормально....хотя get запросы работают. Если пробовать у них на сайте и смотреть в инспекторе то сначала делается запрос на proxy. И получает proxy-token. Может в этом причина

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Спасибо! Теперь я хоть спокоен) я уж думал, что со мной что-то не так) proxy я просмотрел, возможно API вообще на другом сервере физически, ну и ладно, в конце концов пусть тогда разбираются с API. Я уже и так долго объяснял, что такое CORS и почему из браузера не проходят кроссдоменные запросы и что нужно, чтобы они проходили.

Comment: я зарегался на сайте и сделал свой `post api`, но такая же проблема. Get проходит нормально

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц ну да, это проблема API, однозначно, я тоже как только не пробовал. Сюда написать - это была последняя инстанция). Как тут Вам + поставить?))) Я первый раз пишу сюда)))